# How to test CMMotionManager is working?

Tags: ios, swift, cmmotionmanager

I have the following swift code and I tried to test whether the CMMotionManager is working, but every time I use the shake gesture on simulator, the result is not what I expect but a undo tying notification.

```
let manager = CMMotionManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    if manager.deviceMotionAvailable {
        manager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 0.02
        manager.startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) {
            [weak self] (data: CMDeviceMotion?, error: NSError?) in

            if data?.userAcceleration.x < -2.5 {
                self?.resLabel.text = "Shaked"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What controls do you have in the view? Is a UITextField in focus or was it recently?

Comment: I have a UITextField and UILabel on my view

Answer (score 2):

The simulator does not simulate any motion. You have to use a physical device to test anything with CMMotionManager.